# How do you unit test Google Cloud NDB code?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

The recommended path for upgrading a Python 2 AppEngine app to the new runtime is to switch datastore code to Google Cloud NDB. However, I can't find anything about unit testing code that uses Cloud NDB (which was previously possible using the Python 2 testbed library).

How can Cloud NDB code be unit tested? (apart from standard abstracting the Cloud NDB dependency yourself)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apparently](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/yuAofPuxYtE/KQYeFUcBCgAJ), there is no way to unit test Cloud NDB code anymore. The only testing solution available is the Cloud Datastore Emulator.

Comment: what you say  if we mock, datastore_query https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqlz7.png